# _ah/admin does not work with Openshift?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, capedwarf

I just managed to deploy a CapeDwarf app using the template in Openshift, however when I try to access `_ah/admin` it asks for OpenID but throws this error anyway:

```
> OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain:
> http://api-mynamespace.rhcloud.com/_ah/login?other=true&continue=%2F_ah%2Fadmin
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, no idea. Check if Google's OAuth / OpenID docs have something on it.